# PHP Get Attribute of Tag

Tags: php, html, attributes

I have a string of HTML content stored in the database. The parent tag has an attribute that I need to access the value of.

```
HTML: <p lang="en" langDirection="rtl">CONTENT HERE</p>

<?php echo $request->requestDescription; ?>
```

How can I go about getting the value of the `lang` attribute in the string of text? Every thing I have seen so far is using xpath and it seems like over kill for something like this.

Any native functions for getting attributes?

Comment: You can use DOMDocument or Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a simple html string and nothing more, you can do it with a regular expression, else use one of the DOM libraries.

```
preg_match('/lang="(.+?)"/', $yourString, $matches);
$lang = $matches[1];
```

Here is proof that the regular expression works:
https://regex101.com/r/rA2pS9/1

preg_match documentation link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) or [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

> **This function tries to return a string with all NULL bytes, HTML and PHP tags stripped from a given str**. It uses the same tag stripping state machine as the [fgetss()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetss.php) function.

---

Try this

```
<?php echo strip_tags($request->requestDescription) ?>
```

---

Example

1. [PHP `strip_tags()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

Comment: did you check this